# Group and Traspose Excel with multiple values

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerquery

I have this Excel table here:

```
    SUPPLIER    |DOC|STATUS  |
    ------------+---+---------
    Ace         |A  |OK      |
    Ace         |B  |KO      |
    Ace         |C  |NA      |
    Gamma       |A  |KO      |
    Gamma       |B  |KO      |
    Gamma       |C  |KO      |
    Winter      |B  |OK      |
```

I want to traspose the data like this:

```
    SUPPLIER    |DOC.A  |DOC.B  |DOC.C  |
    ------------+-------+-------+--------
    Ace         |OK     |KO     |NA     |
    Gamma       |KO     |KO     |KO     |
    Winter      |-      |OK     |-      |
```

How can I traspose the data like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load into powerquery with data...from table/range ... [x] use rows as headers

click select DOC column

transform ... pivot column

for values column choose STATUS and in advanced options choose dont aggregate

file .. close and load ...

[image]

[image]

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Source, List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[DOC]), "DOC", "STATUS")
in #"Pivoted Column"
```